# Quais as diferenças entre esses pacotes NuGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Eu utilizo o pacote JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie em minhas webapps em asp.net mvc, encontrei mais 2 pacotes JavaScriptEngineSwitcher qual a diferença entre eles 
quais o prós e contras?

- JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8
- JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jurassic
- JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JavaScriptEngineSwitcher`](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher) é um pacote que permite alternar implementações de motores Javascript, sendo que cada um desses pacotes que você indicou representa uma das alternativas possíveis de serem utilizadas dependendo das que você queira usar.

São elas:

- **JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jint:** [motor Javascript baseado no JInt](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)

  Este é um interpretador, ele não compila o código.
- **JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8:** [motor Javascript baseado no V8 (i.e. usado no Chrome)](https://code.google.com/p/v8/)

  Como é baseado no V8, pode-se dizer que é muito confiável. Só que requer uma DLL de código nativo.
- **JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jurassic:** [motor baseado no compilador Javascript -> .Net](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic)

  O projeto é meio antigo, então na medida que o Javascript muda com novas versões é possível que deixe de suportar recursos atuais.
- **JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie:** motor baseado no Internet Explorer (IE deve estar instalado)

  Baseado no IE. Logo o IE deve estar instalado. O Mono por exemplo não vai suportar isso no Linux.

Comment: Decidi usar o JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 só que ele depende das Dlls msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll do Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012. A minha dúvida é, só preciso copiar as Dlls para a pasta bin da minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC ou tenho mesmo que instalar o Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 no servidor?

Eu geralmente posto minhas webapps em hospedagens compatilhadas tipo Locaweb, lá eles não permitem instalar o Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012, realmente só é preciso copiar as Dlls ou tem algo mais para funcionar?

Comment: Possivelmente será apenas uma questão de copiar essas DLLs junto. Se não funcionar é porque a app não tem permissão para carregar as DLLs nativas, o que quer dizer que terá de entrar em contato com o host ou então mudar para outro que permita.